# Minimize subwindow to tab in pyqt

Tags: python, tabs, pyqt, widget, qtabwidget

I am fairly new to PyQT and currently studying how to implement subwindows in mdi area. I was wondering if it's possible in PyQT to minimize subwindow in such way that close/expand/minimize buttons are hidden once the subwindow is minimized. By default minimized subwindows group in such way:

[image: Example]

What I would like to achieve is basically no buttons visible and only title of the subwindow - double clicking on the title would expand the subwindow.

```
 import sys
 from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
 from PyQt4.QtCore import *
 from PyQt4.QtGui import *

 class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
     count = 0

     def __init__(self, parent=None):
         super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
         self.mdi = QMdiArea()
         self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)
         bar = self.menuBar()

         file = bar.addMenu("File")
         file.addAction("New")
         file.addAction("Cascade")
         file.addAction("Tiled")
         file.triggered[QAction].connect(self.windowAction)
         self.setWindowTitle("MDI demo")

      def windowAction(self, q):

         if q.text() == "New":
             MainWindow.count = MainWindow.count + 1
             sub = QMdiSubWindow()
             sub.setWidget(QTextEdit())
             sub.setWindowTitle("subwindow" + str(MainWindow.count))
             self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
             sub.show()

         if q.text() == "cascade":
             self.mdi.cascadeSubWindows()

         if q.text() == "Tiled":
             self.mdi.tileSubWindows()

      def main():
          app = QApplication(sys.argv)
          ex = MainWindow()
          ex.show()
          sys.exit(app.exec_())

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: You may want to consider using QTool Windows or QDockable Widgets.